# php - data still submits after validation return false

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been trying to create a sign-up form and I've tried several methods but the last I added to it is the else if ($status = "OK") line. Below is part of my code please help I'm still new in coding;

```
<?php
$surnameErr = $firstnameErr = $usernameErr = $emailErr = $passwordErr = $password1Err = "";
$surname = $firstname = $username = $email = $password = $password1 = "";
$status = "OK";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["surname"])) {
     $surnameErr = "Surname is required";
     $status = "NOTOK";
   } 
   else {
     $surname = test_input($_POST["surname"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$surname)) {
        $surnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
        $status = "NOTOK";
        }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
       $firstnameErr = "First Name is required";
       $status = "NOTOK";
   } 
   else {
     $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname)) {
            $firstnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
            $status = "NOTOK";
        }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
     $usernameErr = "Username is required";
     $status = "NOTOK";
   } else {
     $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
     $status = "NOTOK";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Invalid Email format"; 
        $status = "NOTOK";
        }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
     $passwordErr = "Password is required";
     $status = "NOTOK";
   } 

   if (empty($_POST["password1"])) {
     $password1Err = "Repeat password to confirm";
     $status = "NOTOK";
   }

   if ($password != $password1){
       echo "<script>alert('Password does not match')</script>";
       $status = "NOTOK";
   }

    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "church") or die(mysqli_error());

    $checkuser = mysqli_query ($connection,"SELECT * FROM signup WHERE username = '$username'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows ($checkuser) > 0){
        echo "<script>alert('$username already exist in our database, please enter another one')</script>";
        $status = "NOTOK";
    }

    $checkemail = mysqli_query ($connection,"SELECT * FROM signup WHERE email = '$email'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows ($checkemail) > 0){
        echo "<script>alert('$email already exist in our database, please enter another one')</script>";
        $status = "NOTOK";
    }

    else if ($status = "OK"){
        $password=md5($password);
        $datainsert = mysqli_query ($connection, "INSERT INTO signup (surname, firstname, username, email, password) VALUES ('$surname', '$firstname','$username','$email','$password')") or die(mysqli_error());
            echo "<script>alert('Sign Up Successful!')</script>";
        }
   }   

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: Tagged `phpmyadmin` why?

Comment: Can you please add some more info to your post. Which alerts are you seeing when you run this page? Which ones do you expect to see? Is there a function of some sort this code is in? It seems like you have an extra close bracket after your else if condition.

Comment: `$status = "OK"`? Should it not be `$status == "OK"`?

Answer (score 1):

Your condition

```
if ($status = "OK")
```

will always be true  because what you're doing is an assignment , not a  comparison.
You need to use "==" to check the value of $status.

Like this:

```
if ($status == "OK")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    else if ($status = "OK"){
```

This line means "Set $status to the value of "OK" and return that value".  This will always be true unless you set $status to a value that PHP considers empty (0, false, NULL, empty string, etc).

It needs to be `else if ($status == "OK"){` to work.

On a side note, you can avoid this class of error if you put the constant or function/method call on the left of the test.  As you can't assign values to function/method calls or constants during normal execution the code will fail with a fatal error, which is then quite easy to debug.

```
    else if ("OK" = $status){ // Will fatal with a line number.  Fixable in 2 seconds flat
```